# Not all features available in OSM exports in TileMill?

Tags: openstreetmap, tilemill

I'm using TileMill and OSM Bright to style an OpenStreetMap for hiking. The problem is that OSM Bright does not import all the OSM features for styling.

I believe it's possible to add features in the osm-bright.osm2pgsql.mml file, but I'm not certain how. Does anyone know how to add, for example, path labels?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how: open the osm-bright.osm2pgsql.mml file and find the minorroad_label id. Then simply add "path" to the table values. [Here's the file on GitHub.](https://github.com/hmarcks/osm-bright/commit/081395e12514e425680ce34188a642069087de27)